# Does C++ Actor Framework guarantee message order?

Tags: c++-actor-framework

Can C++ Actor Framework be used in such a way that it guarantees message ordering between two actors? I couldn't find anything about this in [the manual](http://www.actor-framework.org/manual/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only two actors communicating *directly*, CAF guarantees that messages arrive in the order they have been sent. Only multi-hop scenarios can cause non-determinism and message reordering.

```
auto a = spawn(A);
self->send(a, "foo");
self->send(a, 42); // arrives always after "foo"
```

At the receiving end, it is possible to change the message processing order by changing the actor behavior with `become`:

```
[=](int) {
  self->become(
    keep_behavior,
    [=](const std::string&) {
      self->unbecome();
    }
  );
}
```

In the above example, this will process the `int` before the `string` message, even though they have arrived in opposite order at the actor's mailbox.